# I don't know how to sort the positive and negative numbers

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int A[6][6], i, j, k, max, min;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: "<<endl;
        for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            cout << " " << A[i][j];
        }
    }
    if (j > 0)
    {
        cout << "A: "<<endl;
    }
    else if (j < 0)
    {
        cout << "B: "<<endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    char ch1;
    cin>>ch1;
    return 0;
}
```

I've been looking through the codes here but they all include things I haven't yet learned in C++, I need to make it so the positive numbers are are put in section A and the negative ones in B, and to show them again in that order. How do I do that?

Comment: PLEASE indent your code.  This is unreadable.

Comment: What do you mean? It looks fine to me http://puu.sh/pccs7/d76c28c362.png

Comment: I have edited your question to format your code in a more readable format

Comment: Why the 2D array `A[6][6]` ? Why not `A[36]` or no array at all since you do not really need to store the numbers?

Comment: That's what they've taught me in class for now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you do understand that your loop runs for 6 times and keep asking to enter numbers until you enter 36 inputs.

I would recommend using a 1D array instead of a 2D array. And reduce the number if you can or add a functionality to stop taking inputs when the user think it's enough. You could do this easily with a if condition.

Anyway just to make your code do what it suppose to do(If i get it correctly),

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int A[2][2], i, j, k, max, min;
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: "<<endl;
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            if (A[i][j] > 0)
    {
        cout << "A: " << A[i][j] <<endl;
    }
    else if (A[i][j] < 0)
    {
        cout << "B: "<< A[i][j] <<endl;
    }
        }

    }

    cin.get();
    char ch1;
    cin>>ch1;
    return 0;
}
```

You can change the last for loop like this.I have changed the array size to 2 since I can't enter 36 inputs.What's wrong with your code is that the second set of for loops finish running and print all the numbers and after that it runs the if statement which is again not correct because you are checking the value of j instead of checking the numbers you entered.Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: thanks, now i get it, I tried to do something similar but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can include  then use sort function. In sort function you can write a sort method or you can use greater () as a sort method

Answer (score 0):

The `j` variable is not initialized in

```
if (j > 0)
{
    cout << "A: "<<endl;
}
else if (j < 0)
{
    cout << "B: "<<endl;
}
```

It is not the same `j` as those which are used for the `for` loops since these ones are declared in the loop (with `int`).

Be careful to use only initialized variables.

Also I think you just need to make another `for` loop with `i` and `j` to check whether every element of the array is positive or negative (how about zero elements?).